# How do I add arrays in BigQuery SQL?

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

I have a UDF which returns a floating point array of the same size for each row of a table. How do I sum values of these arrays ?

In other words, how can I do something like this:

```
create temp function f(...)
returns array<float64>
...;
select sum(f(column)) from table
```

As the **result** of this operation I need to get another **array** of equal size where

```
result[i] = sum(over rows) f(row, column)[i]
```

Comment: some input/desired output always help to understand what you are trying to do :)

Comment: @hlagos existing BigQuery SUM() aggregation function does not work with arrays. So I wonder if there is some trick to do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function that uses `ANY TYPE` in order to support summing arrays of `FLOAT64`, `INT64`, or `NUMERIC` along with some sample input:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION ElementWiseSum(arr1 ANY TYPE, arr2 ANY TYPE) AS (
  ARRAY(SELECT x + arr2[OFFSET(off)] FROM UNNEST(arr1) AS x WITH OFFSET off ORDER BY off)
);

SELECT arr1, arr2, ElementWiseSum(arr1, arr2) AS result
FROM (
  SELECT [1, 2, 3] AS arr1, [4, 5, 6] AS arr2 UNION ALL
  SELECT [7, 8], [9, 10] UNION ALL
  SELECT [], [] UNION ALL
  SELECT [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
);
```

It unnests `arr1` using `WITH OFFSET`, then retrieves the equivalent element from `arr2` using this offset, and orders by the offset to ensure that the element order is preserved.

Edit: to sum across rows, you can unnest the arrays, compute sums grouped by the offset of the elements, then reaggregate the sums into a new array:

```
SELECT
  ARRAY_AGG(sum ORDER BY off) AS arr
FROM (
  SELECT
    off,
    SUM(x) AS sum
  FROM (
    SELECT [1, 2, 3] AS arr UNION ALL
    SELECT [7, 8, 9] UNION ALL
    SELECT [4, 5, 6] UNION ALL
    SELECT [10, 11, 12]
  ), UNNEST(arr) AS x WITH OFFSET off
  GROUP BY off
);
```

Comment: Thanks @Elliot Brossard. Give me a hint please, how do I use this approach to sum 20000 arrays returned by my UDF from 20000 rows in my table ?

Comment: I misunderstood what you were asking. See if this edit helps.

Comment: Yes, @Elliot Brossard. I got the idea. I wonder would this "unnest/sum/group by offset" approach scale to array size ~10K ? I will have to test it.

Comment: There is a limit of 100 MB on the size of arrays, but if you mean that you have 10K different arrays, then yes, it should be fine.

Comment: My case is in the range of 10-100K rows, and each row generates an array of, say, 10K elements and I want to sum over these 10-100K arrays and the result will be a single 10K element array. @Elliot Brossard

Answer (score 1):

So based on your comment, what you are looking for  is the `sum` the values of all your arrays. This is how you can do it using `UNNEST` operator

```
WITH mydata  AS (
  SELECT [1.4, 1.3, 1.4, 1.1] as myarray
  union all 
  SELECT [1.4, 1.3, 1.4, 1.1] as myarray
  union all 
  SELECT [1.4, 1.3, 1.4, 1.1] as myarray
)

SELECT SUM(eachelement) from mydata, UNNEST(myarray) AS eachelement;
```

Comment: Thanks @hlagos , but this is not what I was looking for. Your suggestion gives me single scalar. I am looking for way to get an array with element-wise sums: [4.2, 3.9, 4.2, 3.3].

Answer (score 0):

If you have your UDF defined (takes in a your column(s) and returns a `float64` array of a pre-determined (or fixed) dimensions), you can use a simplified solution. For example in case of 3-d arrays, something like:

```
create temp function f(...)
returns array<float64>
...;

with dataset as (
  select arr[offset(0)] as col_a, arr[offset(1)] as col_b, arr[offset(2)] as col_c
    from (
       select f(mycolumn) as arr
       from `mydataset.mytable`
    )
)

select [sum(col_a), sum(col_b), sum(col_c)] as new_array from dataset
```

Comment: Thanks @khan. I thought about it, but the arrays I have are ~10K long.

Comment: You mean these are 10k dimensional arrays?

Answer (score 0):

This does not directly answer OP's question, but people landing on this page searching for "How do I add arrays in BigQuery SQL?" might benefit.

(Based on @elliott-brossard answer edit) In case you have 2 arrays, but 1 array includes a struct, you can use the following code to add them together:

```sql
WITH mydata AS (
  SELECT
    [1, 2, 3] AS arr
    -- ,[7, 8, 9] AS arr2
    ,[
      STRUCT(7 AS timeOnSite)
      ,STRUCT(8 AS timeOnSite)
      ,STRUCT(9 AS timeOnSite)
    ] AS arr2
)

SELECT
  (
    SELECT
      ARRAY_AGG(sum ORDER BY off) AS arr
    FROM (
      SELECT
        off,
        SUM(x) AS sum
      FROM (
        SELECT arr UNION ALL
        -- SELECT arr2
        SELECT (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t.timeOnSite) FROM UNNEST(arr2) AS t)
      ), UNNEST(arr) AS x WITH OFFSET off
      GROUP BY off
    )  
  ) AS sum_arrays
FROM 
  mydata
```